# INDEX(SMALL(IF equation only returning one criteria instead of multiple

Tags: excel, if-statement

I'm using the following formula to return the end time for multiple classes. However, it is only returning multiple results for certain class pairs but not all. I can't seem to find the issue in the equation.

```
{=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($I:$I,SMALL(IF(($H:$H=$B$2)*($J:$J=$C$2),ROW(H:H)),ROW(3:3)))),"",INDEX($I:$I,SMALL(IF(($H:$H=$B$2)*($J:$J=$C$2),ROW(H:H)),ROW(3:3))))}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the top cell containing this *array formula* ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent The formula is in cell B1. However, I copied the formula from cell B2 though. Sorry.

Comment: I personally have a harder time with something like this when I cannot see some small sample data that you want it to work with.